# How to get the list of available aliases in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

Cypress Version: 12.13.0

Is there any way to get the list of available aliases in Cypress? I checked in many forums, i didn't find any solution

If any alias doesnt exist, then it will throw an error like below

```
cy.get() could not find a registered alias for: @Test4
Available aliases are: Test1, Test2, Test3
```

This is clearly shows that, there is some way to print the aliases. Can some one please help with that method?